# change status active/inactive using ajax in yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->status==true) {
            return Html::a("Inactive", "#", ['id' => $data->id, 'class' => 'a_status']);                    
        }
        else {
            return Html::a("Active", "#");
        }
]
```

The problem is, this code is not returning "id" attribute in link. So, wanted to know if this is currect way to put link in grid view or can someone point me correct way?'

Thx in advance.

Comment: in function only return $data->id and check what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing one closing parenthesis and a change in `format` key's value -

Try -

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'format' => 'raw',                //It was 'html' before
    'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->status==true) {
            return Html::a("Inactive", "#", ['id' => $data->id, 'class' => 'a_status']);                    
        }
        else {
            return Html::a("Active", "#");
        }
    }                                 //missing parenthesis
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing a lot of code. Here are some observations.

*) I am using this kind of definition for the column

```
'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
```

I am not sure if it makes a difference, try it this way maybe this is the problem.

Other things:
*) why are you using return

```
Html::a("Inactive", "#", ['id' => $data->id, 'class' => 'a_status']);
```

and not something like

```
Html::a("Inactive", ['change-status', 'status' => 'active', 'id' => $data->id], ['class' => 'a_status']);
```

You are creating in this way the link with the proper url already. If somebody does not have javascript enabled it will still work for them, just with a refresh.

Now you can create a global ajax function that you can reuse with ease for a lot more screens.

Now the actionChangeStatus function can end like this

```
if(Yii::$app->request->getIsAjax()) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
    return ['success' => true];
} else {
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

My ajax looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            "type": "GET",
            "url": element.attr('href'),
            "cache": false,
        })
        .success(function ( response ) {
            $.pjax.reload({container: "#main-pjax", async:false, timeout: 4000});
        });
```